# Image scaling issue in Safari / Webkit based browsers

Tags: html, css, safari, webkit

I'm facing an issue that is unique to only Safari / Webkit browsers.

Have a look at this example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: lime;
  max-width: 400px;
  line-height: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

.row {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

img {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/800x449/383838/949191" />
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/800x449/383838/949191" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In here I have a container with two `inline-block` elements. Both `inline-block` elements contain a `800 x 449px` image.

When rendered, the image scales down in half since the container is set to a max-width of `400px`. i.e the image is rendered as `400px x 224.5px`

The issue is that in Safari, the image's height seems to be scaled incorrectly causing the background-color of the container to show. This issue isn't present in Chrome or Firefox. This seems to only happen when the scaled height is not a round number. i.e in this case the scaled height is `224.5px`. I feel this is due to a rounding error somewhere during rendering.

[image]

Is there any work around to fixing this?

The constraints are:

- I need to use the display the rows as `inline-block` elements
- Contents need to be responsive. i.e if the view port is smaller that 400px, the container should reduce in size which should cause the image to scale down proportionally